# ZTE Blade S2E not enough space

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory, zte-blade, sd-ext, s2e

I have just installed 4.2.2 PAC and S2E later. I have everything on sd-ext, there's 1600MB free space on sd-ext, and 140MB inside. However anytime i want to install an app, it says there's not enough free space.

I have restored some apps with MyBackup Root. I think that was the problem. How to solve it? I don't want to wipe data, I've made some important changes.

(system 219MB/220MB)
(cache 1MB/37MB)

Comment: can you confirm the free space on your `/data` a.k.a internal partition? It is not clear whether the values 1600Mb and 140Mb are free space and if so on what area.

Comment: I've edited it.

Comment: It's still unclear to me. The "insufficient memory" error usually pops up when free space on *internal memory* drops below 25 MB. Do the "140MB inside" refer to free space on *internal (device) storage", or "internal sdcard"? Best would be to inlcude/link a screenshot from *Settings->Storage* (if you cannot include it, simply provide the link in a comment).

Comment: [Image](http://androbin.hu/upload/img1.png) This shows non-avaliable/maximum.

Comment: Might be best to post across to Modaco's Blade forum instead of here as you're bound to find the solution there, fwiw, that ROM you're referring to - some people have had problems with S2E on JB (which is *unofficial*)... just saying ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the S2E on 4.2.2. I wiped everything, it worked. Now I reinstalled S2E and it won't work.

EDIT:
main user had no access to write sd-ext. I created a code added init.d to set sd-ext with chmod 777.